# Find the total number of digits in the following case.

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

> Two numbers $2^k$ and $5^p$ are expanded first then written side by
>   side i.e. adjacent to each other. Find the total number of digits in
>   that case if $k = p = 2004$.

My approach :

$2004\times \log 5 = 1400 $
so number of digits would be $1401$.
$2004 \times log 2 + 1 = 604$
Total digits $= 2005$

Comment: what is the expansion base here?

Comment: Decimal, apparently. OP you should be more explicit with your roundings.

Comment: The log which I have taken here is with base 10.

Comment: Then,I think your result is fine.

Comment: More precisely $2004 \times \log 5 = 1400.7\ldots$ and $2004 \times \log 2 = 603.26\ldots$  but apart from that you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in base 10 you have the number of digits of $x$ as $\lfloor \log_{10} x\rfloor+1$. Assume logs are to base 10 to simplify notation.

The number of digits you need is then, as you calculate:

$\lfloor \log {2^p}\rfloor+1+\lfloor \log {5^p}\rfloor+1 = \lfloor p\log {2}\rfloor+1+\lfloor p\log {5}\rfloor+1$

Aside from the fact that you might have a rounding error of 1, you can then use $p\log2+p\log5=p\log{10}=p$.

So your answer will be $p+2 \text { or } p+1$

Then note, as Henry points out, that the logs are related - the floor function always reduces the total by 1 and never by zero, because the logs are not rational, so the answer is $p+1$

Comment: I don't think "you need to know the logs accurately enough".  It will always be $p+1$ for integer $p=k$

Comment: So my approach is correct, sirs?

Comment: @Henry You are right, of course, because the remainders of the two floor terms are not independent of one another, but sum to 1, and as you noted in your answer, the logs are not rational, so you never get a zero. I will modify accordingly.

Comment: @Bazinga: Yes, your approach works (though there is some rounding) and would work for more general $k$ and $p$

Answer (score 2):

Your method works though for integer $k=p \gt 0$ you do not even have to calculate the logarithms.

Since $k \, \log_{10}(5) + k \,\log_{10}(2) = k \, \log_{10}(10) = k$ and the logarithms are not rational numbers, then the number of digits of the concatenated number must be $k+1$.